# C# Unable to load DLL - HRESULT: 0x8007007E occurs for application with Japanese culture

Tags: c#, exception, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, cultureinfo

I have a c# application which imports unmanaged dll(which is also built by me) and uses it.
Recently  migrated the application from VS2017 to VS2022.
Now the application crashes whenever it could not find the redistributable.
Previously, application will just show warning alone but now it is crashing.

Strange, but this happens only in systems with ja-JP culture.

I manually installed [VS2022](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) redistributable and the crash no longer happens.
That too by mistake I first installed x86. still no use. only it accepts x64.

Any special setup for Japanese culture?. why particular in that culture alone?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has little to do with Japanese culture. But just to be sure, you can use Visual Studio Installer to reinstall the Japanese language pack in Language packs.

[image]

**Key points:**

According to your description, you were able to solve this issue after installing VS2022 redistributable. This shows that the system with Japanese culture lacks the runtime component for running C++.

Because Visual C++ Redistributable is used for applications that need to run C++ developed using Visual Studio and dynamically linked to libraries. You can use these to run such applications on a system that does not currently have Visual Studio installed. It will install these runtime components: C Runtime (CRT), Standard C++, MFC, C++ AMP, OpenMP.

Visual C++ is not only a C++ compiler, but also a visual integrated development environment (IDE) based on the Windows operating system; Visual C++ is composed of many components, including the editor, debugger, program wizard AppWizard, and class wizard Class Wizard and other development tools, these components are integrated into a harmonious development environment through a component called Developer Studio; this running component contains the relevant component content of VC++ 2015-2022. If the old version has been installed, the relevant files will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks @WenbinGang. Though I install the language packs. it will work fine in  my local. If I share this as application, do you think this solution will work?

Comment: @SindhuN I think the issue lies with that system, not your application. What are the problems you are facing now and the functions you want to achieve?

Comment: I build an application in c# which will import c++ dlls through which  information such as gpu memory, utilization etc.  will be fetched. 
Now particularly in japanese systems, my c# application could not fetch the c++ dll and hence it crashes while launching. Not only in a particular japanese system, similiar another japanese system also encounter this problem. This is not happening in en-US systems.